# Doctrine request crash with composite key

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm facing a big problem with Doctrine when i'm requesting a table with a composite primary key referencing foreign keys.
I have a 3 entities: 
Library(**idLibrary**,adress), Book(**idBook**,title,pageCount), Container(***idLibrary***,***idBook***, quantity).

Everything is generated without any errors but when i'm doing findAll() request on my Container repository my browser freezes and nothing is showed like it was stuck in a loop (there 3 rows in my Container table).

```
class Bibliotheque
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="adress", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $adress;
}
class Conteneur
{    
/**
 * Many Containers have One library.
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Bibliotheque")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="libraryId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $library;

/**
 * One Container has One book.
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Livre")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $book;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
 */
private $quantity;
}
class Livre
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="pageCount", type="integer")
 */
private $pageCount;

/**
 * Un livre a plusieurs auteurs
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Auteur")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="books_authors",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $authors; 
}
class Auteur
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthDate", type="date")
 */
private $birthDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, please use only French or English for class name and variable.

Add id inside class "Container" and remove annotation @ORM\id for attributes "library" and "book"

Define attribute "authors" with ArrayCollection and add method getAuthors(), addAuthor(Author $author), removeAuthor(Author $author)

And rename the tables name => "name_id" not "nameId"

look documention http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

```
class Library
{
/**
* @var integer $id
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string $address
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $address;
}

class Container
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

private $id;

/**
 * Many Containers have One library.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Library")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="library_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $library;

/**
 * One Container has One book.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Book")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $book;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
 */
private $quantity;
}

class Book
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $title
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string $pageCount
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_count", type="integer")
 */
private $pageCount;

/**
 * A book have many authors
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $authors
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Auteur")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="books_authors",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $authors;

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getAuthors()
{
    return $this->authors;
}

/**
 * @param Author $author
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function addAuthor(Author $author)
{
    $this->authors->add($author);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Author $author
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeAuthor(Author $author)
{
    $this->authors->removeElement($author);

    return $this;
}
}

class Author
{
/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $firstname
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $firstname;

/**
 * @var string $lastname
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $lastname;

/**
 * @var DateTime $birthDate
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthDate", type="date")
 */
private $birthDate;
}
```